# lateinit property myListener has not been initialized

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, kotlin-lateinit

this is the error
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myListener has not been initialized
at com.example.fitnesscult.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:30)
at com.example.fitnesscult.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:11)

in this adapter

```
package com.example.fitnesscult

import android.app.Activity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView

class MyAdapter(var yogaArrayList: ArrayList<YogaData> , var context : Activity ) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    private lateinit var myListener: onItemClickListener



    interface onItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClicking(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener : onItemClickListener){
        myListener = listener
    }

// to crate new view instances when layout manager fails to find a suitable view fir each item
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.eachyoga,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView,myListener)
    }

// populate items with data
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var currentItem = yogaArrayList[position]
        holder.hTitle.text = currentItem.yogaName.toString()
        holder.hImage.setImageResource(currentItem.yogaImage)
    }

//how many list  item are present in your array
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return yogaArrayList.size
    }
// it holds the view so views are not created everytime, so memory can be saved
    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View, listener: onItemClickListener):                                   RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val hTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.yogaTittle)
    val hImage = itemView.findViewById<ShapeableImageView>(R.id.yogaImage)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onItemClicking(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

}

i was using this adapter to show images and text in recycler view

Comment: You never called the function `setOnItemClickListener()`

Comment: Never use `lateinit` in classes where the entry point is simply the constructor. There's no need and it just invites bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Before use myListener you check is initialize or not

you check this then you can't get this error like lateinit property myListener has not been initialized

```
if (::myListener.isInitialized) { }
```